# Does an online library of formulas exists for mathematical ones?

Tags: math-mode

I was wondering if a library of mathematical expressions in Latex was existing on the web (I don't know if the library term is appropriate) which would help us copy and past them. It would save a lot of time when using, for instance the normal law...

PS: I'm not sure of the tag below, tell me it's not the right one, I will change it right away.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would you consider the equations `x_1^2+x_^2=x_3^2` and `y_1^2+y_^2=y_3^2` to be the same, or different? If you choose the second option, I'd say that (a) the number of possible math expressions (and their representations in TeX!) is pretty much unbounded and (b) having a repository of TeX-encoded equations is not going to be useful for most authors since notation can and does vary so much between authors.

Comment: Of course there is difference between these equations, but a centralized hub for the most usual equations (and even math symbol) which take some time to be written, I was wondering if there where!
For instance for the math symbol I always refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:LaTeX_symbols
But for math formulas, (like the covariance for instance or the negative binomial law, which are more or less formalized) it is always a long waste of time. It would be useful to save time then.
Isn't there even a project for such a library of formulas?

Comment: Wikipedia comes close to being a repository of mathematical formulae.You may have noticed that the formulae featured on Wikipedia are rendered as images, but typeset using LaTeX. You can find their LaTeX syntax by inspecting the image (right-click and select “image properties” in your browser) and looking at the replacement text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [latexsearch](http://latexsearch.com/) by springer. According to the site

> The Springer LaTeX search lets you search through over 8,223,138 LaTeX code snippets to find the equation you need.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I haven't used it though.

Comment: unfortunately, the material on which this search is based isn't really edited for adherence to "best practices", and i've seen a lot of code that, while the output looks like what is wanted, wouldn't convert properly if run through a tool to convert it to mathml or html.

Comment: That's a very nice tool, which could be improve however. I its a bit difficult to find an exact formula. I think the best advice given was to examine element on wikipedia. I didn't thought about it, I was only searching on the screen a latex section...